# Voltage drop with Microwave

Tags: circuit-breaker, voltage

I've begun having problems with the voltage dropping when running the microwave (which is noticeable when the microwave slows down!).  This does not happen with other high drawing appliances (washer/dryer/AC).

I checked the breaker box.  Both lines from outside are stable around 120 when the microwave runs.  However there's a fizzing and crackling that I can't quite source.  I replaced the circuit's breaker itself, which appeared a bit rusty, but that had no effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I will get with an electrician. Don't be penny-wise and dollar foolish. Any fizzling or cracking sound should be checked out asap.

Comment: The fizzling sound is in the panel, you say? Have you checked the circuit's neutral wire land on the neutral bar?

Answer (score 2):

Since the problem does not happen with other appliances, it sounds like this is a problem with this one *circuit*. You have already swapped the breaker, so that leaves:

- Wire
  If this is 14AWG wire/15A circuit, try a 20A circuit (which should be 12AWG wire) if you have one available. That should help generally with voltage drop, but NOT with any fizzing and crackling.
- Receptacle
  The receptacle itself *could* be bad, and is easy to replace. But more commonly it isn't actually *bad* but rather has bad connections.
- Connections
  This is the most likely source of the problem. A bad connection (typically a back stab connection, but can also happen with a screw connection that is coming apart) can cause voltage drop (due to less wire connected than there should be, making that connection a limiting factor in the circuit) as well as other more serious problems (fizzing & crackling are not just noises).

#### Get this fixed before you have a fire!

This is a classic case for AFCI - Arc Fault Circuit Interrupters. They are required in many circuits now but not required in old circuits unless you change things. However, they are also typically not required in kitchens because there the emphasis is on GFCI. In any case, an AFCI "listens" for the type of problems you describe due to bad connections, frayed insulation and other problems.

I would start with the receptacle. I would put in a GFCI unless the circuit is already protected by a GFCI elsewhere (in which case I would install a new regular receptacle). **Don't use the back stab connections**. Strip a little (not too much - don't want to cut off too much of the wire) fresh wire if there is any sign of damage - pitting, burn marks, etc. - and connect the new receptacle. If that doesn't solve the problem, check and reconnect/replace any other receptacles on the same circuit. If *that* doesn't solve the problem then you may have a wiring problem *inside your walls* which would generally require professional help.

Answer (score 1):

That crackle is called **arcing** or an **arc fault**.  It is serious business, and will explain the voltage drop.  It will also create dangerous amounts of heat.

If you are literally hearing it (acoustically) then you must be quite near it. Keep looking.

In the breaker panel, you checked the hot, *but there are two additional wires*.  You can generally disregard **ground**, because current doesn't normally flow on the that.  However all the current that flows on hot *returns on **neutral***. If you heard it in the panel, I would make a beeline for the netural wire of that circuit.

Don't stop until you find it.  If you don't find it, replace the plain breaker with a combination AFCI breaker (CAFCI, which does not include GFCI functionality).

The usual reason for a screw-lug terminal to arc is *that it was under-torqued*.  This is why torque screwdrivers are now mandatory. It can also be due to the wire snapping off from cracking due to over-torque.

As far as your breaker swap, now you know it isn't the breaker, review that choice.  For instance if it's a GE panel and you replaced a GE breaker with an Eaton BR, that would make things *worse* not better.  Needless to say, if you sink $40+ into an AFCI breaker, get a correct type for your panel.